# Announcing a site sponsorship for DevOps Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, site-sponsorship

My name is Jascha, and I'm a Product Manager for Advertising at Stack Overflow.

I'm excited to announce that **New Relic has generously agreed to sponsor the DevOps site** for the upcoming 3 months, as a part of [our site sponsorship program](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange) and after successful experiences on both our [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) and [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) sites. New Relic wants to support the DevOps Stack Exchange site as part of an ongoing effort to provide resources to the DevOps community.

And to reiterate some of the clarifications we've made on the previous posts surrounding this site sponsorship program:

#### How does a sponsorship affect this site?

Site sponsorships are administered much like the "tag sponsorships" you may have seen on other sites. Apart from the visual updates and site promotion, you should not see any significant changes in the scope or the operation of this site. Site sponsorship is essentially "strategic philanthropy" where industry partners like New Relic can give back to DevOps communities by having a presence on the site, and to provide a place to help ask and answer questions.

#### Let's get an immediate concern out of the way

Sponsors do not "own" these Q&A sites — they work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now. Any ads a sponsor might submit still have to go through our strict ad editorial process, as has always been the case. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

**Update January 2021**

We're happy to announce that New Relic has agreed to sponsor the DevOps Site for another 3 months (Jan 2021 - Mar 2021).

Comment: Previous sponsorships of the same kind have led the beta sites [Quantum Computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/) and [Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) to get a custom design, like graduated sites. Will this happen for DevOps too, or not, given the relatively short period of sponsorship?